# Interpretation of GAMM with Factor level Predictors

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, frequentist

I'm running the following model in R using the package *mgcv*:

```
gamm(richness ~ s(exp.time, by = expgroup) + expgroup, random = list(exp.call=~1),family = Gamma(link = "log"), data=df.snake)
```

This model structure was selected after using AIC values to determine whether more complex random effects structures, the inclusion of a temporal autocorrelation term, or different distribution families produced a more efficient model fit

The parameters included in this model are

- richness - Count data of the OTU richness of an animals microbiome
- exp.time - days since the experiment began
- expgroup - Treatment group (either inoculated with disease or sham inoculation)
- exp.call - subject ID

Using the functions *appraise* and *draw* from the package *gratia*, please find visualizations of model fit and output below:

[image]

[image]

Summary of the model is as follows:

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
richness ~ s(exp.time, by = expgroup) + expgroup

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.59794    0.05050  91.041   <2e-16 ***
expgroup1   -0.03179    0.05050  -0.629     0.53    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                 edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(exp.time):expgroupinoculated 3.217  3.217 5.648 0.000866 ***
s(exp.time):expgroupsham       1.000  1.000 3.947 0.048936 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0834   
  Scale est. = 0.22217   n = 144
```

I have two questions regarding intepretations of this model.

1. Experimental group, as a parametric term, does not have a significant effect on richness. However, time has a significant effect on richness for both treatment groups. How can I interpet this result? Does this mean that there is actually no difference between the predicted trends for each factor level?
2. The relative edf for the trendline for the sham treatment group is 1.000. My understanding is that this indicates the trendline approximates a linear trend. However, the p-value for this term is significant. My understanding is that the null hypothesis for this test is that the trendline is linear. Is this just a quirk of the somewhat arbitary nature of alpha values?

Thank you greatly for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

No; first there are differences in the response between the levels of the factor — the estimated difference in the overall mean of the reference level and `expgroup1` level is not zero (it's ~-0.03179), even if the estimated effect is not *significantly different from zero*.

As far as the smooth terms go, there's nothing here that specifically addresses the *difference* between the estimated smooth effects. These tests are Wald-like tests of the null hypothesis that the estimated smooth is a flat function (a constant = 0).

You might deduce that the estimated smooths are different because of the EDF, so they have different estimated *shapes*, but as there is no information about the uncertainties in the estimated smooths you aren't able to conclude anything more about the differences.

To answer your question you need to consider what you mean by the estimated trends. If you mean the shapes of the smooths, then you could compute the difference of the estimated smooths and the uncertainty in that difference. I have  a posts on how to do this here: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/

If you want to know if the estimated functions on the response scale, so including the mean response you need to compute differences on the response scale, and then do some posterior simulation to estimate the uncertainty on the estimated differences.

### Q2

No; as I mentioned above, the test is for a constant function, not a linear function.

Comment: Dr. Simpson,

Thank you very much for your response and the software packages you have written which I use regularly. The tutorial you linked is actually, in part, what led me to post this question. I went through your tutorial and was able to generate the difference between estimated smooths (https://imgur.com/a/MhSRt6L). I was mostly looking to confirm that it is appropriate to run this comparison based on the summary of the initial model. I was also curious if there is a test statistic that accompanies this comparison or if this metric is primarily represented visually. Again, thank you!